# UITableView is getting a gap on top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, xcode5

Iam not sure if it is the appropriate question to ask right now. I am working with Xcode 5 (preview version ) on the table view. The issue right now is if my table view is selected as `group` than I am having a gap between the first cell and the top edge of table.

The code for uitable view delegate is below

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 8;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %d",indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Image below when I am choosing `group` in the xib

[image]

However, if i am switching to `plain`, table is normal

[image]

Any thoughts for this situation. I googled it but seems there are nothing out there. Any helps are welcomed here.

Comment: Umm didnt you notice the settings app? I think thats how the new grouped table view works.

Comment: @NilsMunch this is actually a good question and should be reopened on the Sept 18th. This is not off topic by any means. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/should-moderators-enforce-ndas-for-software-vendors

Comment: Here's how I solved this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18938763/588253

Comment: If this was indeed closed due to Apple's information embargo, it should now be reopened.

Comment: It works for me when I return a very small number (i.e. 0.0001f) for tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:

Comment: This is not expected behaviour actually. Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst/21137552#21137552

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That is the expected appearance of a grouped table view in iOS 7. If you open the Settings app you will see a similar separator bar at the top of the table and in between each section in the table view (grey in color).

Comment: Ugh :( Why, why did they have to break it :( my username/password login thingy using a grouped UITableView is broken now in all my apps :(

Comment: Hmm, the changes on grouped UITableView are the ugliest among other changes in iOS7 ...

Comment: Jake, You are correct.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I've been killing myself trying to get rid of that gap.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of being thorough you should implement the number of sections in the table view and in this case, return one. Its possible that theres a bug with Xcode 5 wherein if you do not implement that method it provides you with an incorrect header.

If that does that not solve the issue I would recommend implementing

```
- (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)headerViewForSection:(NSInteger)section
```

That may do the trick as well.