# Gap at top of UITableView with PLAIN cells

Tags: uitableview, ios7, xcode5

Does anyone know why a `UITableView` inside a `UIViewController` always has a gap above the `UITableViewCell`. I'm aware that this is expected for Grouped cells, but this is a Plain cell.

How can I remove the gap?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[[self UITableView] setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-65, 0, 0, 0)];

That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

One of the proposed answers to the quesion [UITableView is getting a gap on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679052/uitableview-is-getting-a-gap-on-top) solved this for me, although it's not the approved answer.

> Just add this code in ViewDidLoad
>
> `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;`

Alternatively, you can set this property on the ViewController in the storyboard.